# SQL Increment count on duplicate values

Tags: sql

Not sure if my title correctly states what I'm after, but I've the following table.

```
[ID] [ROWID]
 10
 11
 11
 12
 13
 13
```

And I'm trying to create this, whereby a ROWID will be generated for each ID.

```
[ID] [ROWID]
 10     1
 11     2
 11     2
 12     3
 13     4
 13     4
```

I thought I might have been able to use the ROW_NUMBER() window function on H2, but I haven't been able to get anything working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank`. In case of tie it will assign the same number.

```
select
    ID
    ,dense_rank() over (order by ID asc) as [ROWID]
from yourTable
```

If you can't use `dense_rank()` you can simulate it using pure SQL:

```
SELECT ID,
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) 
 FROM yourTable AS O2
 WHERE O2.ID < O1.ID ) + 1 AS [ROWID]
FROM yourTable AS O1;
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible another way? DENSE_RANK isnt a valid function in the version of H2 I am running(cant update)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DENSE_RANK()](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dense_rank_aggregate) window function.

The query will be:

```
 SELECT ID, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS ROWID
 FROM Table
```

As mentioned in the document

> If two or more rows have the same values in `ORDER BY` columns, these rows get the same rank.

I'm unable to test the query H2, so verified in SQL Server. [Demo link in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e53b7359acc8fb95ab6df11527604749)

Comment: Hi, is it possible another way? DENSE_RANK isnt a valid function in the version of H2 I am running(cant update)